# SQL rows to 2 columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a data row with columns A, B, C, D, E, F... 
How could I write a sql select to have the result:

```
Col1, Col2
A,    B
C,    D
E,    F
...
```

EDIT:
There will be only one row and dynamic number of columns. And I am not allowed to use information_schema and sys tables. Also would be interesting to know how to do it for entire table (multiple A,B,C,D,E.. rows), not the only row.

Comment: Do you want a solution for both Oracle and Sql Server?

Comment: Are you required to have a SQL-based solution?

Comment: Adrian, it doesn't matter, I just need one solution.

Comment: mellamokb, yes I have to do it on sql

Comment: Are your columns dynamic, or can you use a hard-coded list of columns?

Comment: I am confused right now, I tried using multiple UNION, pivot but didn't get the desired result. Maybe somebody has an idea?

Comment: mellamokb, they are dynamic, there might be H, G.. columns

Comment: Will there always only be one row? Also, as you answer these questions we are asking, you may want to update your question to make it more complete.

Comment: How are you obtaining this row? If the number of columns is not fixed the query you are looking for will most likely have to be dynamic. But I guess the query that produces the row is dynamic too. If so, my question will be: why use two dynamic queries instead of one?

Comment: Well I have this on a paper right now and just think how should I solve it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you know the list of columns ahead of time, it should be as simple as unioning each group of two columns together:

```
;with Data as (
    select 'A' as A, 'B' as B, 'C' as C, 'D' as D, 'E' as E, 'F' as F
)
select A,B from Data union
select C,D from Data union
select E,F from Data
```

If the list of columns is dynamic, you will need Dynamic SQL to process.  Here's a fully-working example using a test table with 11 columns:

```
create table Test (id01 int,id02 int,id03 int,id04 int,id05 int,id06 int,id07 int,id08 int,id09 int,id10 int,id11 int);
insert Test values (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11);

declare @select varchar(max)
;with ColumnInfo as (
    select
        row_number() over (order by column_name) - 1 as rownumber,
        column_name
    from information_schema.columns
    where table_name = 'Test'
)
select
    @select = coalesce(@select + ' union ' + char(13) + char(10), '') +
        'select ' + max(case when rownumber % 2 = 0 then column_name end) +
        ',' + coalesce(max(case when rownumber % 2 = 1 then column_name end), 'NULL') +
        ' from test'
from
    ColumnInfo
group by
    rownumber / 2

exec(@select)
```

Sample Input:

```
id01 id02 id03 id04 id05 id06 id07 id08 id09 id10 id11
1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10    11
```

Sample Output:

```
id01 id02
1    2
3    4
5    6
7    8
9    10
11   NULL
```

Live Demonstration: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d0507/1

Answer (score 4):

using unpivot you could do this . [See it working](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c615c/24)

```
WITH piv1 
     AS (SELECT foo, 
                bar, 
                Row_number() OVER (ORDER BY bar) rn 
         FROM   test p 
                UNPIVOT (foo FOR bar IN (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6) ) 
                AS unpvt) 
SELECT t1.foo col1, 
       t2.foo col2 
FROM   piv1 t1 
       INNER JOIN piv1 t2 
         ON t1.rn = t2.rn - 1 
WHERE  t1.rn % 2 = 1
```

If you want to make it dynamic you just need to make this part dynamic

`UNPIVOT (foo FOR bar IN (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6) )`

Comment: @mellamokb yeah its awesome. fellow SOer [Jake Feasel](http://stackoverflow.com/users/808921/jake-feasel) built it

Answer (score 1):

With MS SQL you can use this trick:

```
DECLARE @s VARCHAR(max)

SET @s=''

SELECT @s=@s+','+val FROM (
SELECT Col1 AS [val] FROM [your table]
UNION ALL 
SELECT Col2 FROM [your table] ) as [data]
ORDER BY [val]
SELECT @s
```

With PostgreSQL:

```
SELECT string_agg( "val",',') FROM (
SELECT Col1 AS "val" FROM "your table"
UNION ALL 
SELECT Col2 FROM "your table"
ORDER BY 1 ) AS "data"
```

MySQL:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( `val`,',') FROM (
SELECT Col1 AS `val` FROM `your table`
UNION ALL 
SELECT Col2 FROM `your table`
ORDER BY 1 ) AS `data`;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the column names displayed (and not to unpivot the data of the one row) you can use the `information_schema`:

```
SELECT a.column_name AS col1
     , b.column_name AS col2
FROM 
    information_schema.columns AS a
  LEFT JOIN
    information_schema.columns AS b
        ON  b.table_schema = 'database_name'
        AND b.table_name = 'table_name' 
        AND b.ordinal_position = a.ordinal_position + 1
WHERE a.table_schema = 'database_name'
  AND a.table_name = 'table_name'  
  AND a.ordinal_position % 2 = 1 ;
```

Comment: Probably it will work, but I am not allowed to use information_schema.

Comment: You're not allowed to use `information_schema`?  How else do you expect to get the list of columns in the table?

Comment: No, after your edit, no. This will not do what you want. This would show the column names, not the data of the one row.

Comment: You could always [test it here](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/65454)

Comment: @ConradFrix: Why did you remove your answer? I think the OP wants that, not what I did. Or a combination of the two (which would be impossible, since he comments he can't use the `information_schema`)