# Select newest records that have distinct Name column

Tags: sql

I did search around and I found this
[SQL selecting rows by most recent date with two unique columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189213/sql-selecting-rows-by-most-recent-date)
Which is so close to what I want but I can't seem to make it work.

I get an error Column 'ID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

I want the newest row by date for each Distinct Name

```
Select ID,Name,Price,Date
From  table
Group By Name
Order By Date ASC
```

Here is an example of what I want

Table

| ID | Name | Price | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | A | 10 | 2012-05-03 |
| 1 | B | 9 | 2012-05-02 |
| 2 | A | 8 | 2012-05-04 |
| 3 | C | 10 | 2012-05-03 |
| 4 | B | 8 | 2012-05-01 |

desired result

| ID | Name | Price | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | A | 8 | 2012-05-04 |
| 3 | C | 10 | 2012-05-03 |
| 1 | B | 9 | 2012-05-02 |

I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2008

Comment: I've a geniuine question, why does SQL make this operation this hard? seems a very common requirement..

Answer (score 75, accepted):

```
Select ID,Name, Price,Date
From  temp t1
where date = (select max(date) from temp where t1.name =temp.name)
order by date desc
```

Here is a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/6a8e3/1) with a demo of the above

---

Or as Conrad points out you can use an INNER JOIN (another [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/6a8e3/384) with a demo) :

```
SELECT t1.ID, t1.Name, t1.Price, t1.Date 
FROM   temp t1 
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT Max(date) date, name
    FROM   temp 
    GROUP BY name 
) AS t2 
    ON t1.name = t2.name
    AND t1.date = t2.date 
ORDER BY date DESC
```

Comment: While this does work you can't create a tie-breaker without some field concatenation. Which is why I typically use an inner join instead [like this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e7382/7) when not using row_number()

Comment: @ConradFrix agreed, that was the second version that I was going to post, I just got this one done first.  I will edit my answer with the second option as well. thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I went with the first part of this and it works percectly.  Tie breaker will not be a concern since I am actually using a datetime, and the chances of two datetimes matching are less then the chances of me winning the lottery.  I appreciate your help on this guys.

Comment: The first SQL declaration above helped me out. Thanks for saving my life.

Answer (score 21):

There a couple ways to do this. This one uses ROW_NUMBER. Just partition by Name and then order by what you want to put the values you want in the first position.

```
WITH cte 
     AS (SELECT Row_number() OVER (partition BY NAME ORDER BY date DESC) RN, 
                id, 
                name, 
                price, 
                date 
         FROM   table1) 
SELECT id, 
       name, 
       price, 
       date 
FROM   cte 
WHERE  rn = 1
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bbd4d/3)

Note you should probably add ID `(partition BY NAME ORDER BY date DESC, ID DESC)`  in your actual query as a tie-breaker for date

Comment: This looks very complicated, I will give a go and report back how it works

Comment: I am not saying this method doesn't work, but there are too many question Unanswered for me, I can't access the demo (work internet has blocked that page)  and instead of bothering you guys with more questions I tried one of the other answers which seems to be working for me.  +1 upvote since I have no doubt it works

Comment: @K'Leg do you know why your work internet is blocking sqlfiddle? I ask because sqlfiddle.com is my site (I'll try not to take it too personally, heh).

Comment: They block all sites that have no category   "This Websense category is filtered: Uncategorized."

Comment: @JakeFeasel looks like you might be able to do something about it here http://www.websense.com/content/URLCategories.aspx

Comment: @JakeFeasel My Pleasure. And thanks for building SQLFiddle. As I've [said before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9916489/sql-rows-to-2-columns/9916741#comment12656059_9916741) its awesome.

Comment: @K'Leg great! Hope you find it useful.

Comment: Just a note to say that, if SQL Fiddle does not work for you try disabling uBlock (or your chosen adblocker). Also, consider supporting the site by whitelisting it in your adblocker settings.

Answer (score 8):

```
select * from (
    Select
        ID, Name, Price, Date,
        Rank() over (partition by Name order by Date) RankOrder
    From table
) T
where RankOrder = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found another memory efficient way (but probably crude way)that has worked for me in postgress. Order the query by the date desc, then select the first record of each distinct field.

```
SELECT distinct on (Name) ID, Price, Date from
table
order by Date desc
```

Answer (score -9):

Use **Distinct** instead of **Group By**

```
Select Distinct ID,Name,Price,Date
From  table
Order By Date ASC
```

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187831.aspx

Comment: Msg 145, Level 15, State 1, Line 9
ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.