# SQL How to select max dates from results of a join

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

I am a bit new to SQL on the whole and I managed to stumble my way through this far but now I am a bit stuck.

I have two tables one is an index of "Ships" to "Oil Types" just Id's. The other table "ROB" is the amount of oil remaining on the ship.

Each month I may or may not get a new record in the ROB table.

What I need is each distinct oil type for a cetain ship and the latest ROB if there is one.

The following query nets me almost what I want, except I get all ROB's for each oil type and I want only the latest.

```
PARAMETERS QueryShipID Short;
SELECT Oils.OilID, Oils.ShipID, ROB.LastROB, ROB.Received, ROB.DateReceived, ROB.PortReceived, ROB.TotalUsed, ROB.CurrentROB, ROB.DateSent
FROM 
    (SELECT DISTINCT OilID, ShipID 
    FROM [Index] 
    WHERE (((ShipID)=[QueryShipID])))  
    AS Oils 

    LEFT JOIN 

    (SELECT ShipID, OilId, LastROB, Received, DateReceived, PortReceived, TotalUsed, CurrentROB, DateSent 
    FROM [Oil ROB])  
    AS ROB 

    ON (Oils.ShipID = ROB.ShipID) AND (Oils.OilID = ROB.OilID);
```

What I need to do is get the last DateSent for each oil type.

I have found a few tutorials on using the Max function which seem to suggest joining the results of an aggregate query back to the orginal table. However I can't seem to get this to work and it makes a huge and messy query.

If anyone has some tips on the best way to do this I would be very grateful.

Ideally after doing this I would like to add a parameter for date so you can get the last ROB before a certain date. This should be relatively easy but I include it in case it has any bearing on the answers.

Thanks you.

Dave

Comment: What table does the oil type live in?

Comment: Technically the type lives in another table that is related by OilID to the Index and ROB tables. But it isn't really important yet... I can get to that later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks nawful

I am posting the answer myself as it is a slight modification of what nawful posted. Also the link K'leg posted was helpful so thanks.

This gets me exactly what I want...

```
SELECT    Oils.OilID, Oils.ShipID, ROB.LastROB, ROB.Received, ROB.DateReceived,  
          ROB.PortReceived, ROB.TotalUsed, ROB.CurrentROB, ROB.DateSent 
FROM  
          ( 
           SELECT DISTINCT OilID, ShipID  
           FROM   [Index]  
           WHERE  ShipID = [QueryShipID] 
          ) AS Oils             
LEFT JOIN   
          ( 
           SELECT ShipID, OilId, LastROB, Received, DateReceived, PortReceived,  
                  TotalUsed, CurrentROB, DateSent  
           FROM   [Oil ROB]  
          )  AS ROB ON Oils.ShipID = ROB.ShipID AND Oils.OilID = ROB.OilID
WHERE     ROB.DateSent = ( 
                          SELECT MAX(DateSent)  
                          FROM   [Oil ROB]  
                          WHERE  ShipID = ROB.ShipID AND  
                                 OilID = ROB.OilID
                         );
```

The main modification is that I need the OilID from [Oil ROB] table to match the ROB.OilID not Oils.OilID. Also I moved the WHERE to the outermost SELECT.

Couldn't have done it without you though :)

Comment: Yes thats the right way to do: I did not test or give much thought to that part when writing that answer

Answer (score 0):

I think I asked almost this exact same question recently try this  [SQL Select newest records that have distinct Name column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10452940/sql-select-newest-records-that-have-distinct-name-column)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT    Oils.OilID, Oils.ShipID, ROB.LastROB, ROB.Received, ROB.DateReceived, 
          ROB.PortReceived, ROB.TotalUsed, ROB.CurrentROB, ROB.DateSent
FROM 
          (
           SELECT DISTINCT OilID, ShipID 
           FROM   [Index] 
           WHERE  ShipID = [QueryShipID]
          ) AS Oils 

LEFT JOIN  

          (
           SELECT ShipID, OilId, LastROB, Received, DateReceived, PortReceived, 
                  TotalUsed, CurrentROB, DateSent 
           FROM   [Oil ROB] 
           WHERE  DateSent = (
                              SELECT MAX(DateSent) 
                              FROM   [Oil ROB] 
                              WHERE  Oils.ShipID = ROB.ShipID AND 
                                     Oils.OilID = ROB.OilID
                             )
          )  AS ROB ON Oils.ShipID = ROB.ShipID AND Oils.OilID = ROB.OilID;
```

Comment: Thanks I never thought to do it like that... although it can't get Oils.ShipID or OilIR or ROB.ShipID or OilID from inside the WHERE.

Comment: If I move the WHERE outside I get only the records with the latest date not the latest date for each record. I will p[lay some more :)