# SQL: Select single item per name with multiple criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to select a single item per value in a "Name" column according to several criteria.

The criteria I want to use look like this:

1. Only include results where IsEnabled = 1
2. Return the single result with the lowest priority (we're using 1 to mean "top priority")
3. In case of a tie, return the result with the newest Timestamp

I've seen several other questions that ask about returning the newest timestamp for a given value, and I've been able to adapt that to return the minimum value of Priority - but I can't figure out how to filter off of both Priority and Timestamp.

[Here is the question that's been most helpful in getting me this far.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10453083/4991083)

Sample data:

```
+------+------------+-----------+----------+
| Name |  Timestamp | IsEnabled | Priority |
+------+------------+-----------+----------+
|  A   | 2018-01-01 |     1     |    1     |
|  A   | 2018-03-01 |     1     |    5     |
|  B   | 2018-01-01 |     1     |    1     |
|  B   | 2018-03-01 |     0     |    1     |
|  C   | 2018-01-01 |     1     |    1     |
|  C   | 2018-03-01 |     1     |    1     |
|  C   | 2018-05-01 |     0     |    1     |
|  C   | 2018-06-01 |     1     |    5     |
+------+------------+-----------+----------+
```

Desired output:

```
+------+------------+-----------+----------+
| Name |  Timestamp | IsEnabled | Priority |
+------+------------+-----------+----------+
|  A   | 2018-01-01 |     1     |    1     |
|  B   | 2018-01-01 |     1     |    1     |
|  C   | 2018-03-01 |     1     |    1     |
+------+------------+-----------+----------+
```

What I've tried so far (this gets me only enabled items with lowest priority, but does not filter for the newest item in case of a tie):

```
SELECT DATA.Name, DATA.Timestamp, DATA.IsEnabled, DATA.Priority
From MyData AS DATA
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT MIN(Priority) Priority, Name
  FROM MyData
  GROUP BY Name
) AS Temp ON DATA.Name = Temp.Name AND DATA.Priority = TEMP.Priority
WHERE IsEnabled=1
```

[Here is a SQL fiddle as well.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/52e72/2/0)

How can I enhance this query to only return the newest result in addition to the existing filters?

Answer (score 0):

Use `row_number()`:

```
select d.*
from (select d.*,
             row_number() over (partition by name order by priority, timestamp) as seqnum
      from mydata d
      where isenabled = 1
     ) d
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Mostly the same answer as mine posted almost at the same time.

Comment: @LuisCazares . . . 2 minutes earlier is not exactly "almost the same time" ;)

Comment: Does this still work if timestamps are not in any order?

Comment: @FreddyTheHorse . . . SQL tables represent *unordered* sets so your question doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 0):

The most effective way that I've found for these problems is using CTEs and `ROW_NUMBER()`

```
WITH CTE AS(
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY Priority, TimeStamp DESC) rn
  FROM MyData
  WHERE IsEnabled = 1
  )
SELECT Name, Timestamp, IsEnabled, Priority
From CTE
WHERE rn = 1;
```